# looking for NLP libraries that supports Arabic language

Tags: python, nlp, arabic, chatbot

I want to develop a chatbot using python

and im looking for NLP libraries that supports Arabic language

any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [wit.ai](https://wit.ai/) is supporting Arabic, I haven't used it myself but heard some good things about it!

Comment: Thanks , i have another question i want to make an android app chatbot which language should i use and which libraries

Comment: I think you should make a new question for this. I don't have any knowledge of developing apps.